# Unit test to ensure all required services are added to the .Net Core DI container

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection

My team maintains a very large .Net Core 2.1 web site. Lots of controllers, lots of services that get injected into the controllers via constructor injection.

Sometimes due to developer error a service class is no longer added to the DI container during startup. Obviously this leads to an exception when MVC tries to construct a controller that relies on that service (in response to an incoming request).

Problem is that this may affect only some lightly used controller, so our (far from perfect) regression testing doesn't pick up the regression bug. But it is still bound to be picked up by one of our (very demanding) customers.

I though of writing a unit test that would

1. Instantiate a ServiceCollection class (that implements IServiceCollection);
2. Call our own method that adds all services to that service collection (the same method used during normal startup);
3. Find all controllers through reflection, and try to construct them the same way MVC does - by getting dependent services from the DI container.

So my question is:

- Does this approach make sense?
- Is there an example somewhere that I could use?
- Failing an example, how would I achieve 1) and 3) ?

Comment: (1) - var serviceCollection = new Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollection();

Comment: To me, this makes a lot of sense. It is for this exact reason that containers like Castle Windsor, StructureMap, and Simple Injector actually have built-in features that verify your registrations. Simple Injector even does additional checks beyond checking if the object graph can be constructed. With MS.DI, however, you will have to build such verification logic yourself. There's nothing built-in.